# Do South African citizens need a visa to enter Dubai?

Tags: visas, transit, uae, south-african-citizens, dxb

Good day we have stopover for 12 hours @ Dubai Airport from Bali to South-Africa.  Do we need a visa to enter Dubai and if so where can it be obtained.

Comment: To enter Dubai you do need a visa since South Africa is on visa nationals list for UAE. Your airline can arrange the visa fairly easily

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   - Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

So if staying in the Transit Zone, you do **not** Need a visa.

Otherwise, you need it, but it can be arranged by the airline for you to get on arrival